# Weightlifting alone

Tags: weightlifting, motivation

I have trained for my initial one year alone and did not see much gain.
But had the opportunity to train with a friend for few months. In these few months I learned to lift heavier weights with good form and push myself further like never before. This helped me gain weight and also some shape in short period of time.

Now I am back training alone for the past few months, I do push myself now and then. But not frequently as much as before.

Could you provide some suggestions/tips to help me motivate myself to keep pushing myself at every rep in every set in every session.

Good upbeat music seems to help. I am unable to find a partner at the moment. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Dave

Comment: Take a look at some of the answers [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2408/how-to-overcome-lack-of-willpower-when-not-having-access-to-a-personal-trainer-or) and [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/41/how-do-you-motivate-yourself-to-keep-exercising).

Answer (score 4):

The internet is full of training partners for you.  You may not be able to train with them but posting results to a public place and creating some form of competition will probably be of great help to you.

This one of the things that has help crossfit become so popular, every workout is a competition and you can post your workouts to the main page comments.

There are also site like fitocracy.com, dailyburn.com, myfitnesspal.com that will help.

Personally I follow the work out of the day (WOD) from http://www.crossfitfootball.com/.  Those workouts all have a benchmark to measure, either time, # or reps or weight.

Comment: Thanks @JustinHamade. fitocracy looks interesting, I will join and will give it a try. crossfitfootball seems to be related to football and strength training, I will keep an eye on it.